# Rails5 - test if current URL is equal to routed path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing

I created a test to confirm that after a failed post request to a signup form the current url is the same it was before. This in the case the default RESTful route takes the place of the custom url. My test passes, but I think is not complete and/or there's a mistake.

**PROCESS:**
creation of a signup page (signup.html.erb) with a signup form using the form_for method:

```
..
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
..
```

route set up for get and post requests to the signup page:

```
..
get '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
resources :users
..
```

Actions for the users controller:

```
..
def new
    @user = User.new
end
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
..
```

test to assert if the current url (after the post request was submitted with invalid data) is equal to the one before the post request, which is the custom path set up in the route.

```
..
test "should keep signup page after failed post request" do
    post signup_path, params:{ user: {  name:  "", email: "user@invalid", password: "123",
                                          password_confirmation: "321" }
                             }
    assert_equal request.fullpath, signup_path
end
..
```

As I wrote, the test passes.
Problem is that it still passes also when the path in *form_for* (signup.html.erb file) is left empty.

In this last case, the url for the signup page, after a failed POST attempt, is not anymore */signup*, it's now the default RESTful route, in my case ***/users***.

**QUESTION:**
Does anyone know why the *request.fullpath* gets associated to */signup* and not to */users* after a failed post attempt?

**NOTE:**
I see this problem also by running *rails test:integration* putting *signup_path* under quotes and no url defined in *form_for*:

```
..        
assert_equal request.fullpath, 'signup_path'
..
```

The failure message:

```
Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_signup_page_after_post_request [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:13]:
Expected: "/signup"
  Actual: "signup_path"
```

But Expected should be "/users" in this case.

Comment: @Gilles Goualiladet I'am sorry, I misunderstood the question. my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`assert_equal 'signup', path` should make the test pass here.

You said you want the same url, but your test is wrong. Also the expectation is the first parameter of `assert_equal`.

It looks like your `redirect_to @user` is incorrect, it should be something like `redirect_to user_path(@user)`